# Saving data from one collection to another collection based on a field value in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have two collections one is Coupons and another is Users. So in my application I want to assign coupons based on user email. Now, in my Coupons collection I want to store the user information (from User collection) as well whose email we just saved in the Coupons collection. So while creating the coupon by entering the email id I want to get the user with the same email_id in the Users collection and save it along with the Coupon I just created in the Coupons collection.

Below is what I was doing and  I was using the populate method but I was saving the _id from the Users collection into the coupons collection and that was working fine until requirements changes and now I want to save it with user_email.

User Collection:

```html
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const hasher = require("wordpress-hash-node");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    first_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 25,
    },
    last_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      min: 3,
      max: 25,
    },
    user_email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
      unique: true,
      lowercase: true,
    },
    user_pass: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    role: {
      type: String,
      enum: [
        "customer",
        "admin",
        "accountant sr",
        "accountant jr",
        "shipping sr",
        "shipping jr",
      ],
      default: "customer",
    },
    billing_phone: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    birth_date: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    userVerified: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    disable: {
      type: Boolean,
    },
    document: [
      {
        url: { type: String },
      },
    ],
    documentVerified :{
     verified:{type:Boolean},
     status:{type:String}
    },
    billingAddress: {
      companyName: {
        type: String,
      },
      streetAddress: {
        type: String,
      },
      city: {
        type: String,
      },
      province: {
        type: String,
      },
      postalCode: {
        type: String,
      },
      country:{
        type:String
      }
    },
    // wishlist:[{
    //    productID: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Products'}
    // }]
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

userSchema.virtual("password").set(function (password) {
  this.user_pass = hasher.HashPassword(password);
});
userSchema.methods = {
  authenticate: function (password) {
    return hasher.CheckPassword(password, this.user_pass);
  },
};
userSchema.virtual("full_name").get(function () {
  return `${this.first_name} ${this.last_name}`;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Coupon Collection:

```html
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const couponSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  couponCode: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  expireDate: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: "",
  },
  isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: true,
  },
});

const Coupon = mongoose.model("Coupon", couponSchema);

module.exports = Coupon;
```

Controller for saving Coupon

```html
const createCoupon = async (req, res) => {
  const { user, email, amount, expireDate, isActive } = req.body;

  function couponGenerator() {
    var coupon = "";
    var possible = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      coupon += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return coupon.toUpperCase();
  }
  const couponCode = couponGenerator();

  try {
    const newCoupon = new Coupon({
      user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user),
      email,
      couponCode,
      amount,
      expireDate,
      isActive,
    });

    await newCoupon.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          status: "ERROR",
          error: err,
        });
      }
    });

    res.json({
      status: "SUCCESS",
      Coupon: newCoupon,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

Result:

My above way works fine if I save _id from User collection while creating Coupon and it generates the user info in the Coupon created. But I need a way I can use the email in the Coupon model and get the user information that has (From users) user_email = email (From Coupons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `Model.aggregate()` where you perform a `$lookup` in the `users` collection and match the `Coupon.email` against the `User.user_email`. This is followed by an optional `$unwind` to get an object because `$lookup` returns an array.

An example would be:

```js
const coupons = await Coupon.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "email",
      "foreignField": "user_email",
      "as": "user_details"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user_details"
  }
]);
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HSWYWwVVfJ_) for a working example.

If you wanted to only get one coupon you can use `$match` to select on any property. For example:

```js
const coupon = await Coupon.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      couponCode: "abc123"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "email",
      "foreignField": "user_email",
      "as": "user_details"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user_details"
  }
]);
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ejo_NEtbJp-) for a working example with `$match`.